# MVC3 binding querystring parameter to deep object property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders, querystringparameter

My domain is setup similar to

```
public class Pagination 
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
}

public class IndexViewModel
{
    public Pagination  Pagination  { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model, Pagination pg, string page)
    {

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

When I navigate to `/?Page=5` I would expect 5 to be the value of model.Pagination.Page to be 5 also, however it appears MVC does not bind query parameters more than 1 layer deep.

What can do I do to change this?

Or is changing this setting up more trouble than it's worth? And I should just do

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model, Pagination pg, string page)
    {
       model.Pagination = pg;

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

*Note the triple parameters are there to illustrate that it won't fill IndexViewModel but it fills both of the other parameters since they're 0 or 1 layer deep.

Comment: The query parameter is not `/?Pagination.Page=5`, so why expect that `model.Pagination.Page` will get set? The model binder should set `pg.Page` (as well as `page`) as you have your signature now, but I think your expectation otherwise is incorrect.

Comment: Hence my question on what would I do to make it fill model.Pagination.page from `page=5`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your method signature be...

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    var model = new IndexViewModel{
                        Pagination = new Pagination { Page = page ?? 1 } };
    if(page.HasValue)
        model.Stuff = StuffGenerator
                          .GetStuff()
                          .Skip(page.Value * _pageSize)
                          .Take(_pageSize);
    else
        model.Stuff = StuffGenerator.GetStuff().take(_pageSize);
    return View(model);
}
```

Your example sounds like a GET but looks like a POST.

Comment: It's a get that can be fed the model through PostRedirectGet with the model being held in tempdata.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: Why does your model and the method signature both have Pagination instances?

Comment: I don't want it to have both, I only want the model to have it but the model won't deeply bind the value. I do need the page value both in the controller and in the view.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: I don't think that is possible.  ModelBinding only occurs on POSTs.  MVC won't parse a URL and bind your model to parts of it.

Comment: @Will maybe I'm using a wrong term somewhere but MVC most definitely fills my Pagination pg and string page parameters on get requests

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: Freaky.  I'm out of my depth, then.  Off to play with the unicorns.  Good luck.